# Converting for loops to while loops in Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert the for loop to while loop. Here it is:

```
for k in range(10,20,5):
    print(k)
```

How can I convert this to while loop? I have Python 3.

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem? Are you merely looking for a while loop that increments k by 5 from 10 to below 20? What have you tried so far? What problem exactly do you have doing this? Do you know how to set a variable, increment it, and check it against a constant? Why do you want to use such an inferior loop in the first place?

Comment: I am just a beginner, so I wanted to know how to do this conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **for loop** of following way  (end>=start)

```
for loop_var in range(start,end,step):
   #code here
```

equivalent **while loop** will be

```
loop_var=start
while loop_var<end:
   #code here
   loop_var+=step
```